# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'loading' of 'state' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

This is my user signup code in **REACTJS**, whenever I hit the signup button the redux for request works and then it goes to request_fail instead of success. And after this when I see my mongo collection then the data is stored perfectly. I checked the API in postman so it is working fine, so I tried my best to resolve the error but not get success.
**It will be a great help if anyone find solution for this**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
    import {
      Container, Col, Form,
      FormGroup, Label, Input,
      Button,
    } from 'reactstrap';
    import { signupuserAction } from '../../redux/actions/users/userActions';
    const Signup = ({ history }) => {
      const [name, setName] = useState('');
      const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
      const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
      const [bio, setBio] = useState('');
      const [jobtitle, setJobtitle] = useState('');
      const [tech, setTech] = useState('');
    
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      //getting user login from store
      const state = useSelector(state => {
        return state.userLogin;
      });
      const { loading, userInfo, error } = state
    
      //Redirecting if user is login/authenticated
      useEffect(() => {
        if (userInfo) {
          history.push('/');
        }
      }, [userInfo])
      const submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //dispatching action
    
        dispatch(signupuserAction(name, email, password, bio, jobtitle, tech));
      }
      return (
        <Container className="signup">
          <h2>Sign Up</h2>
          <Form className="form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <Col>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label for="name">Name*</Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  id="name"
                  placeholder="Enter Your Full Name"
                  onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                  value={name}
                />
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label for="email">Email*</Label>
                <Input
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  id="email"
                  placeholder="myemail@email.com"
                  onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                  value={email}
                />
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label for="password">Password*</Label>
                <Input
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  id="password"
                  placeholder="********"
                  onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                  value={password}
                />
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label>Bio*</Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="bio"
                  id="bio"
                  placeholder="Enter a breif Introduction about Yourself"
                  onChange={e => setBio(e.target.value)}
                  value={bio}
                />
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label>Job Title*</Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="jobtitle"
                  id="jobtitle"
                  placeholder="Sotware Developer"
                  onChange={e => setJobtitle(e.target.value)}
                  value={jobtitle}
                />
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label>Technology*</Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="tech"
                  id="tech"
                  placeholder="ReactJS, NodeJS, Python "
                  onChange={e => setTech(e.target.value)}
                  value={tech}
                />
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
            <Button color="primary" className="btn-submit">Submit</Button>
          </Form>
        </Container>
      );
    }
    
    export default Signup;
```

Comment: Can you share your `userLogin` reducer function and how you combine your reducers to create your store object for your redux provider?

Comment: https://github.com/developerabhijeet/newRepository

Comment: here is the gihtub repository

Comment: @DrewReese above is the link, can you please check it

Comment: I found a possible bug in your action code (*addressed in answer below*), but was unable to trace a path that would lead to `state` (state.userLogin`) being undefined in your `Signup` component. Are you sure this is where you are accessing a `loading` of undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Your `userReducer` function seems ok, so I checked out the `signupuserAction` action. I suspect it's throwing an error in your asynchronous action *after* the successful POST request. I believe you have a logical error in the Promise chain when processing the POST request response.

## Reducer/Action Issue

1. You attempt to console log the response `res.data`. Since `console.log` is a VOID return you actually return `undefined` from the Promise chain.
2. You attempt to destructure `data` from `undefined` and this throws an error.
3. The error is caught by the outer `try/catch` and the `USER_REGISTER_FAIL` action is dispatched.

Action

```
const signupuserAction = (name, email, password, bio, jobtitle, tech) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_REGISTER_REQUEST
      });
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      };
      
      const { 
        data // <-- (2) attempt to destructure from undefined
      } = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/signup', {
        name,
        email,
        password,
        bio,
        jobtitle,
        tech
      },
        config
      ).then((res) => console.log(res.data)) // <-- (1) void return
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      dispatch({
        type: USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload: data
      });
      console.log(data)
      //saving user to localstorage
      //localStorage.removeItem('userAuthData');
      localStorage.setItem('userAuthData', JSON.stringify(data));
    } catch (error) { // <-- (3) catch thrown error & failure action dispatch
      console.log(error);
      dispatch({
        type: USER_REGISTER_FAIL,
        payload: error.response && error.response.data.message,
      });
    }
  };
};
```

Perhaps you meant to parse the JSON, or you wanted to log the result and forgot to return it.

```
const { data } = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/signup', {
  name,
  email,
  password,
  bio,
  jobtitle,
  tech
},
  config
).then((res) => {
  console.log(res.data);
  return res.data;
})
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Regarding the "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'loading' of 'state' as it is undefined" error, I wasn't able to find a path through the code to lead to `state` being undefined. My hunch is it is on *some* initial rendering and your redux state perhaps isn't instantiated yet, but this seems unlikely. You can, however, provide a fallback value for state in your UI to guard against the undefined `state`.

```
const { loading, userInfo, error } = state || {};
```

I left a comment above to double check where the `state` is undefined when attempting to destructure `loading`.

Comment: Thank a lot sir, It means a lot. I will do the mentioned changes and resolve the things you have mentioned.